# unable to write into file

Tags: c, arrays, file, file-io

This is code to write contents in file.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
   FILE *fp;
   char ch(90);
   fp = fopen("books.txt","w");
   if(fp == NULL)
   {
        puts("Cannot open file");
   }
   printf("Enter lines of text:");
   while(strlen(gets(ch)) > 0)
   {
       fputs(ch, fp);
   }
   fclose(fp);
}
```

I'm getting 4 errors. These are:

> 1. Cannot convert `int` to `char *` in function `main()`.
> 2. Type mismatch in parameter `__s` in call to `gets(char *)` in     function `main()`.
> 3. Cannot convert `int` to `const char *` in function `main()`.
> 4. Type mismatch in parameter `__s` in call to `fputs(const char *,FILE *)` in function `main()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your definition of the char array is wrong I believe:

```
char ch(90);
```

must be

```
char ch[90];
```

Comment: can you post the full output of your compiler

Comment: I close my source file, then reopen and complied it.. and it works. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 2):

In your code

```
 char ch(90);
```

is *considered* as a function declaration, which is not what you want. you need to use the `[]` operator to denote an array, like

```
 char ch[90];  //array named ch having 90 chars
```

After that, in case `if(fp == NULL)` is success (i.e., file opening is failed), just printing out a message is *not* sufficient. You should not use the returned `fp` further anywhere in the program, i.e., you have to skip all the statements involving that `fp`. Otherwise, using *invalid* file pointer will result in [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said,

1. never use `gets()`, use `fgets()` instead.
2. the proper signature of `main()` is  `int main(void)`.

Comment: From the error messages it seems the compiler used by the OP considers `char ch(90);` a declaration with initialization (`C++` style).

Comment: @halex Just addressed that issue. :-)

Answer (score 0):

### Firstly:

Your character array definition should be:

```
char ch[90];
```

### Secondly:

Your definition of the `main` should be:

```
int main(void)
```

### Thirdly:

Consider using `fgets()` instead of `gets()`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the  char array definition,

it should be like  char ch[90];